# Passing paths with spaces as arguments in OS X

Tags: macos, bash

I'm having trouble passing a path as an argument which has a space inside.

```
keyLocation="/Users/vladimir/Google\ Drive/file.pem"
ssh -i $keyLocation root@192.168.1.1;
```

This give me the below error:

> Warning: Identity file /Users/vladimir/Google not accessible: No such
>   file or directory.

Basically after the assignment keyLocation itself becomes "/Users/vladimir/Google Drive/file.pem" (no ) so when it tries to use $keyLocation as an argument it passes it as

```
ssh -i /Users/vladimir/Google Drive/file.pem root@192.168.1.1
```

How can I make the ssh command recognise it as a path which has a space inside?

Comment: `$"$keyLocation"`

Answer (score 12):

You mixed it up a little bit. Spaces don't need to be escaped inside quotes. And when you expand a variable containing space, always quote it.

```
keyLocation="/Users/vladimir/Google Drive/file.pem"
ssh -i "$keyLocation" root@192.168.1.1
```

See: [Quotes and escaping [Bash Hackers Wiki]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)

Answer (score 0):

Frank answered it in the comments:

```
$"$keyLocation"
```

Thanks, Frank.

Comment: You can use `"$keyLocation"` instead of `$"$keyLocation"`. `$""` is used for strings that undergo translation depending on the locale. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Locale-Translation.

Answer (score 0):

For me storing the path into a variable did not do the trick.

A different approach is to use a symbolic link

```
ln -s ~/Google\ Drive/ Drive
```

After that you can use

```
ssh -i ~/Drive/file.pem root@192.168.1.1
```

Hope that helps someone else!